# Using iptables TPROXY instead of REDIRECT

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip, nat

I'm running `Debian 8`.
I'm trying to intercept all packets, and are currently using `iptables` for this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000
```

This seems to work, but it removes the possibility to get the original destination port on the packet.

I've read `TPROXY` should be the way to go, as it is not using `NAT`.

I've tried to replace `REDIRECT` with this:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 5000
```

But I'm not intercepting any packets on my service when doing so...

Comment: Are you trying to intercept local packets? The do not go into PREROUTING, you need to use INPUT/OUTPUT for them.

Comment: The doc's says `PREROUTING`: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt. I'm getting `iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.` when trying to use `INPUT` instead of `-t mangle -A PREROUTING`

Answer (score 0):

Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt in kernel tree mentions the following:

> The 'TPROXY' target provides similar functionality without relying on
>   NAT. Simply add rules like this to the iptables ruleset above:
>
> ```
> iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY \
>   --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 50080
> ```
>
> Note that for this to work you'll have to modify the proxy to enable
>   (SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT) for the listening socket.

Did you set the above mentioned options on listening socket in your app?

Please also note that the document above mentiones the need to add appropriate ip routing rule and table to get the packets delivered locally.