# TPROXY is not redirecting all traffic to a specified port

Tags: linux, proxy, udp, nftables, transparent-proxy

I'm writing a UDP transparent proxy in Rust, I'm using several crates

- [socket2](https://docs.rs/socket2/latest/socket2/) => Access to the creation of a RAW socket
- [nix::sys::socket](https://docs.rs/nix/latest/nix/sys/socket/index.html) => Access to all of the low level socket API calls
- [std::net::socket](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html) => Access to the standard socket

the machine that is supposed to act as a proxy has been set as the gateway for the target machines.

The proxy machine has the linux kernel redirection capabilities enabled, see snippet below

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Redirect packets coming to the computer
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

# Disable ICMP redirection
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
```

The machine also has a `NFTABLES` rule set up to redirect all of the incoming traffic to the proxy program, see snippet below

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Setting up NFTABLES

nft add table filter
nft add chain filter divert "{ type filter hook prerouting priority -150; }"
nft add rule filter divert meta l4proto udp socket transparent 1 meta mark set 1 accept

#nft add table ip nat
#nft -- add chain ip nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100 \; }

# Creating a new rule that redirects UDP traffic from P1-P2 to port 35

nft add rule filter divert udp dport 80-65525 tproxy to :35 meta mark set 1 accept

#nft add rule ip nat prerouting udp dport 80-65525 redirect to :35
```

As you can see from the commented out parts, I've experimented with both `NAT PREROUTING` and `TPROXY`.
After extensive research and testing I have found out that when I use `NAT PREROUTING` my proxy (that's listening on port 35) gets ALL of the incoming traffic from the clients but when I read the packets from the socket the original destination address get overwritten with the proxy machine's ip (which I don't want).
But if I instead use `TPROXY` I don't get all of the incoming traffic, I only get what my machine is "supposed" to see, e.g. broadcast traffic and traffic that has the proxy machine's mac address as the destination, this means that I can't see all of the traffic from the connected clients.

I've followed the instructions given in the [linux kernel's tproxy manual](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt).

It has to be noted that I do set `IP_TRANSPARENT`.

These are the things that I set in my program

```rust
use socket2::{Socket, Domain, Type, Protocol};
use std::os::fd::{OwnedFd, RawFd, AsRawFd};
use nix::sys::socket::{
    ...
    sockopt::{IpTransparent, Ipv4OrigDstAddr, Ipv4PacketInfo},
    setsockopt,
    ...
};
...
let client_to_proxy_socket = match Socket::new(Domain::IPV4, Type::RAW, Some(Protocol::UDP)) { ... };
let socket_ref: OwnedFd = client_to_proxy_socket.into();
let active: bool = true;
match setsockopt(&socket_ref, IpTransparent, &active) { ... };   // IP_TRANSPARENT
match setsockopt(&socket_ref, Ipv4OrigDstAddr, &active) { ... }; // SO_ORIGINAL_DST
match setsockopt(&socket_ref, Ipv4PacketInfo, &active) { ... };  // IP_PKTINFO
...
```

When it comes to what I've tried, I must say that I've tried a lot of possible combinations of both rules and code with variations and different structs.

I'm gonna post a short list of links that I've already visited and read multiple times

- [Implement async socket recvmsg for RX and TX timestamping in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880669/implement-async-socket-recvmsg-for-rx-and-tx-timestamping-in-rust)
- [Get destination address of a received UDP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281409/get-destination-address-of-a-received-udp-packet)
- [System-wide redirect traffic to local proxy server using iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/1020374/system-wide-redirect-traffic-to-local-proxy-server-using-iptables)
- [Using iptables TPROXY instead of REDIRECT](https://serverfault.com/questions/927796/using-iptables-tproxy-instead-of-redirect)
- [IPTables configuration for Transparent Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595575/iptables-configuration-for-transparent-proxy)

As for what I expect, I expect to get all of the incoming traffic and have that redirected by `TPROXY` to port 35.

I also posted a similar question on stackoverflow, but it occurred to me that this is not only a programming question, but this could be a network/linux question as well.

I would like to note one more thing, during my testing yesterday I found out that even tho I disabled `ICMP redirection` (see first snippet) I saw that the machine was sending ICMP redirection messages anyway reading them through wireshark, and that's something that left me pretty puzzled.

Comment: In your layout: is the transparent proxy *the* router, ie the address set as gateway by clients? If not you should add a schematic of your network layout, with position of clients, router, transparent proxy and targets. If that's in a virtualization environment such as Docker, don't forget to mention it.

Comment: @A.B It is set as the default gateway for the clients, the machine that has the proxy service (my program) has a real router as his default gateway, and I'm doing this on real metal, no virtual machines or containers involved. So the flow is `Client -> Proxy -> Router -> Internet`

Comment: Maybe the return flow is Internet -> Router -> Client (bypassing the proxy). Can't know without you providing the network layout (with values for precise description). That would then explain why you feel the need to disable ICMP redirects: this should normally not be needed.